# Mac app rejected as not open in new mac OS 10.14

Tags: macos

I have submitted app twice in mac app store and they have rejected with below reason.

---

Guideline 2.3 - Performance

Your app does not achieve the core functionality described in your marketing materials or release notes.

Specifically, App does not launch from Finder. App icon momentarily appears on Dock but quit itself before being launched.

Best regards,
App Store Review

---

While I further followed up with apple then they have informed that app is not open in mac 10.14 OS.

Have any one face similar kind of issue and what is resolution steps for such kind of issue?

Comment: What version of MacOS did you test with before submitting?  Did you test with MacOS 10.14?

Comment: I checked from 10.13.6, I didn't have macOS 10.14. Even I tried to update current version to 10.14 but it not show 10.14 version in mac store.

Comment: Are you able to login to developer.apple.com (with the apple id you use to submit) and use the Download section from there to get 10.14?  Perhaps your Mac is sufficiently old that Mohave isn't supported on it....

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: Thanks, Got it and started to download. but how to fix this issue if it not work in mac 10.14 version?

Comment: Same way you would debug any crash or bug. Run your app under the debugger in XCode...

Comment: If any one have app rejection issue then please check in new Mac OS 10.14.*. App not works properly in Dark appearance. After fix it it approved.